# How do I prevent a section heading from being the last line on a page?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

In a latex document I have got a section heading as the last line on a page, followed by the section content on the following page. How do I prevent this page shift between section heading and section content?

Comment: The default settings in LaTeX _already_ make it _infinitely bad_ to break within two lines of a section heading. So if it is doing that then every other option available was also disallowed. Please supply a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: You probably can't provide a MWE? I at least couldn't provoke this behaviour with a simple example. Normally it's a sign of TeX panicking because it can't typeset some other stuff properly. Hard to say, really, without seeing your document. Do you redefine any typesetting penalty variables? Do you use `microtype` to give TeX more knobs to turn in order to save the day?

Comment: Using \FloatBarrier might work with package placeins for Floats (Figures, tables). I hope there would something available for Sections also